# Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter "ComputerChoice" of "UserInput.UserChoice"

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem that I can't solve

Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter "ComputerChoice" of "UserChoice"

> namespace RockPaperScissors
>
> {
>
> enum GameItems
>
> {
>
> Rock,
> Paper,
> Scissors
>
> }
>
> class Program
>
> {
>
> static void Main(string[] args)
>
> {
>
> int countOfItems = Enum.GetNames(typeof(GameItems)).Length;
>
> Random random = new Random();
>
> Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(GameItems));
>
> GameItems randomGI =
> (GameItems)values.GetValue(random.Next(values.Length));

```
        Console.WriteLine("Pick rock, paper or scissors \n0 for Rock \n1 for Paper\n2 for Scissors\nq to quit");
        string[] yourName = new string[1];

        string userVal = UserInput.UserChoice (new string[3]{ "Rock","Paper","Scissors"}, values);
        
        Console.WriteLine("User selected: " + userVal);
        
        
    }
}
class UserInput
{
    public static string UserChoice(string[] args, Array items, GameItems ComputerChoice)
    {
        string val = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] options = { "0", "1", "2", "q"};
        int index = Array.IndexOf(options, val);
        if (index > -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} found in the array at index {1}", val, index);
            if (!String.Equals(val, options[3]))
            {
                GameItems gameItemByUser = (GameItems)items.GetValue(Int32.Parse(val));
                Console.WriteLine("You picked: " + gameItemByUser);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You selected to quit");
            }
                    
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value not found");
        }

        return val;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your call to the UserChoice method is missing a parameter:

```
string userVal = UserInput.UserChoice (new string[3]{ "Rock","Paper","Scissors"}, values);
```

It needs the third parameter which I'm guessing is randomGI:

```
string userVal = UserInput.UserChoice (new string[3]{ "Rock","Paper","Scissors"}, values, randomGI);
```